# Custom Listview with cardview in android

Tags: android, listview, view, scrollable, cardview

After the card listview i have put the view and another cardview should it work ? i didn't make it scrollable only the custom listview is scrollable after that other cardviews are not displayed.Below is the code:
(here i have cut the code of relative layout attributes only)

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/confirm_order_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="-10dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/confirm_order_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_order_list"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorView"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/shipping_add_card1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_order_view1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shipping_add_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shipping address"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shipping_add_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shipping_add_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:maxLines="5" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the RUN tab in Android Studio? If yes, please post :-)

Comment: No,there is no error.

Comment: If i put the scrollview than it will gives me error.

Comment: Were you using scroll view or nested scroll view? Make sure you use nested one if you want to use it, and add the contents inside another Layout. Don't directly add contents in the scroll vew.

Comment: I have put my view and cardview inside the linearlayout whole linearlayout inside nestedscrollview so my cardview content overwrite over the listview. not properly displayed.